# Searching for an element of one list in another list and replacement

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists as follow:

```
l = {"XY", "XT", "AB", "GT"};
ll = {{"x", "g", "f"}, {"x", "y", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "a", "b", 
    "z"}, {"g", "t"}};
```

for each element in `l` (i.e. `l[[1]]`,`l[[2]]`,`l[[3]]` and `l[[4]]`)
I want to go through `ll` and if the character exist then I replace them with the corresponding element of `l`. For example:
for `l[[1]]` in ll I should have:

```
{{"x", "g", "f"}, {"XY", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "a", "b", 
        "z"}, {"g", "t"}}
```

For `l[[2]]` there is

```
{{"x", "g", "f"}, {"XT", "y", "l"}, {"x", "c", "a", "b", 
        "z"}, {"g", "t"}};
```

for `l[[3]]` I get:

```
{{"x", "g", "f"}, {"x", "y", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "AB", 
        "z"}, {"g", "t"}}
```

and for `l[[4]]` I should get:

```
{{"x", "g", "f"}, {"x", "y", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "a", "b", 
        "z"}, {"GT"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
replace = Replace[ll,{a___,##&@@ToLowerCase[Characters@#],b___}:>{a, #, b}, ∞]&;

replace[l[[3]]]
```

> {{"x", "g", "f"}, {"x", "y", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "AB", "z"}, {"g",  "t"}}

```
replace /@ l // Column
```

> [image]

Also, an alternative way to use `SequenceReplace`:

```
sr = SequenceReplace[{a__ /;(StringMatchQ[StringJoin@a , #, 
   IgnoreCase -> True])} :> #] /@ ll &;
sr /@ l === replace /@ l
```

> True

Comment: thank you for the answer, I just edited my question which was my mistake. Is it possible to have this for orderless set? in which case `replace[l[[2]]]` should give: `{{"x", "g", "f"}, {"XT", "y", "l"}, {"x", "c", "a", "b", "z"}, {"g", "t"}}`

Comment: I did it using: `replace = 
  Replace[ll, {OrderlessPatternSequence[
       a___, ## & @@ ToLowerCase[Characters@#], b___]} :> {a, #, 
      b}, \[Infinity]] &;` :)

Comment: I have added a more generalised version here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185424/searching-and-replacing-element-of-a-list-from-another-list?noredirect=1&lq=1 but so far couldn't work it out

Answer (score 2):

```
SequenceReplace[ToLowerCase@Characters[#] -> # & /@ l] /@ ll
```

> ```
> {{"x", "g", "f"}, {"XY", "l", "t"}, {"x", "c", "AB", "z"}, {"GT"}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @Kuba but as I mentioned in my example I need separate lists for each of `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]`, `l[[3]]` and `l[[4]]`