# Searching and replacing element of a list from another list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have asked a question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185357/searching-for-an-element-of-one-list-in-another-list-and-replacement) which was answered. In this question I want to generalise my case to dealwith string of words. Suppose I have the following lists:

```
l = {"ONIONTOMATO", "BUTTERMILK", "BUTTERWHEAT"};
ll = {{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
   "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
   "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", 
   "vinegar", "wheat"}}
```

I want to look at each `l` ie `l[[1]]`, `l[[2]]` and `l[[3]]`
and make a replacement in `ll`. So that I get 3 lists. For `l[[1]]`:

```
{{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
   "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
   "ONIONTOMATO", "potato", "tamarind", "vegetable_oil", 
   "vinegar", "wheat"}}
```

For `l[[2]]`:

```
{{"BUTTERMILK", "cinnamon", "egg", "starch", "vanilla", 
   "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
   "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", 
   "vinegar", "wheat"}}
```

And for  `l[[3]]`:

```
{{"BUTTERWHEAT", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
   }, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
   "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", 
   "vinegar", "wheat"}}
```

If words in `l` were characters, as in the previous question, one could use

```
replace = Replace[ll, {OrderlessPatternSequence[ a___, ## & @@ ToLowerCase[Characters@#], b___]} :> {a, #, b}, \[Infinity]] &;
```

But I am not sure how to proceed in this case. I have tried to change `Characters` to `String` in definition of `replace`
but this did not work.

**Edit: Please note that my original `ll` size has length of 56498 and my `l` has length of 72390 this methods seems only work for my example. So naturally I am looking for an answer which can be applied.**

Answer (score 1):

function *replace* produces the lists

```
replace[x_] := 
Module[  {g = {}, f, s, p}, 
l = {"ONIONTOMATO", "BUTTERMILK", "BUTTERWHEAT"};
ll = {{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
 "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", 
 "lamb", "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil",
  "vinegar", "wheat"}};
s = ToUpperCase["" <> # & /@ Permutations[#, {2}]] & /@ ll;
g = # & @@ Position[s, l[[x]]];
p = Permutations[ll[[g[[1]]]], {2}][[g[[2]]]];
f = First[# & @@ Position[ll[[g[[1]]]], p[[1]]]];
ll[[g[[1]], f]] = l[[x]];
ll[[g[[1]]]] = DeleteCases[ll[[g[[1]]]], p[[2]]];
ll]
```

here it is

```
replace[1]
```

> {{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
>     "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
>     "ONIONTOMATO", "potato", "tamarind", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", 
>     "wheat"}}

```
replace[2]
```

> {{"BUTTERMILK", "cinnamon", "egg", "starch", "vanilla", 
>     "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
>     "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar",
>      "wheat"}}

```
replace[3]
```

> {{"BUTTERWHEAT", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", 
>     "vanilla"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb",
>      "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", 
>     "vinegar", "wheat"}}

In a more general sense, if you want ALL the lists from list "l" type

```
replace /@ Range[Length@l]
```

Comment: Still problematic, I did as you mentioned and get: `replace[1]` as `{{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
  "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
  "ONIONTOMATO", "potato", "tamarind", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", 
  "wheat"}}` then `replace[2]` as ``{{"BUTTERMILK", "cinnamon", "egg", "starch", "vanilla", 
  "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", 
  "ONIONTOMATO", "potato", "tamarind", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", 
  "wheat"}} which has two capitalised words

Comment: ok. everything is fixed now. try it!

Comment: Thanks for this, I wonder this can be generalised? my original `ll` size has length of 56498 and my `l` has length of `72390` this methods seems only work for my example.

Comment: I have added this as a note to my question and gave you an up-vote.

Comment: thanks. you may also remove the above comments about the repeated calls. Yes, a very large list needs a different approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach (with the same results) for you to try..

the function you have to call is again "replace"

```
replace[x_] := 
Module[  {g = {}, f, s, p}, 
l = {"ONIONTOMATO", "BUTTERMILK", "BUTTERWHEAT"};
ll = {{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
 "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", 
 "lamb", "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil",
  "vinegar", "wheat"}};
s = ToLowerCase@l;
t = Boole[StringContainsQ[s[[x]], #] & /@ ll[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@ll];
tot = Total /@ t;
pos = First[# & @@ Position[tot, 2]];
wor = Flatten@Position[t[[pos]], 1];

ll[[pos, wor[[1]]]] = l[[x]];
ll[[pos]] = Delete[ll[[pos]], wor[[2]]];
ll]
```

Finally this is a more generalized function in case you have to make replacements in more than one sublists:

```
replace[x_] := 
Module[  {g = {}, f, s, p}, 
l = {"ONIONTOMATO", "BUTTERMILK", "BUTTERWHEAT"};
ll = {{"butter", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla", 
 "wheat"}, {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", 
 "lamb", "onion", "potato", "tamarind", "tomato", "butter", 
 "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", "wheat"}};
s = ToLowerCase@l;
t = Boole[
StringContainsQ[s[[x]], #] & /@ ll[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@ll];
tot = Total /@ t;
pos = Flatten@Position[tot, 2];
wor = Partition[Position[t[[pos]], 1], {2}];
worl = Last /@ First /@ wor;
wort = Last /@ Last /@ wor;

Table[ll[[pos[[k]], worl[[k]]]] = l[[x]], {k, Length@pos}];
Table[ll[[pos[[j]]]] = Delete[ll[[pos[[j]]]], wort[[j]]], {j, 
Length@pos}];
ll]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one idea. First, a function that splits a string into two words:

```
wordSplit[s_] := ToLowerCase @ Flatten @ StringCases[
    s,
    StartOfString~~w1__~~w2__~~EndOfString /; AllTrue[{w1,w2},DictionaryWordQ] :> {w1,w2}
]
```

For example:

```
wordSplit["ONIONTOMATO"]
```

> {"onion", "tomato"}

Next, create a function that checks whether both words are present in your list:

```
compoundQ[list_, {w1_, w2_}] := !FreeQ[list, w1] && !FreeQ[list, w2]
```

For your example:

```
compoundQ[ll[[1]], {"butter", "milk"}]
```

> True

If the list contains both words, replace:

```
ireplace[{w1_, w2_}, compound_, l_] := If[compoundQ[l, {w1, w2}],
    Block[{i = 0},
        Replace[l, w1 | w2 :> If[i++ == 0, compound, Nothing], {1}]
    ],
    l
]
```

For instance:

```
ireplace[{"onion", "tomato"}, "ONIONTOMATO", ll[[2]]]
```

> {"bay", "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", "ONIONTOMATO", 
>   "potato", "tamarind", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", "wheat"}

Finally, a function that processes the whole `ll` list:

```
replace[list_, compound_] := With[{w = wordSplit[compound]},
    If[MatchQ[w, {_String, _String}],
        ireplace[w, compound, #]& /@ list,
        list
    ]
]
```

So:

```
replace[ll, "BUTTERWHEAT"]
```

> {{"BUTTERWHEAT", "cinnamon", "egg", "milk", "starch", "vanilla"}, {"bay", 
>     "beef", "black_pepper", "cane_molasses", "lamb", "onion", "potato", 
>     "tamarind", "tomato", "vegetable_oil", "vinegar", "wheat"}}

Comment: This only works for dictionary words...  "vegetable_oil" is in the ll list. Could this code handle "VEGETABLE_OILONION"?